# Stand alone fantasy book about a Roman like civilisation that fights with an army of linked warriors that are almost superhuman

Tags: story-identification, books

The story is about a Roman like civilisation. They are being invaded and their defence is an army of linked warriors - always two to each link, they get their strength and knowledge to fight from their goddess and are almost superhuman. The main story is about a father-daughter link. I read this in 1980s/90s. I had the book but can’t find it now.